# Updated dependencies in angular application left broken

Tags: angular, firebase

I have updated some dependancies trying to fix some security issues. I believe it was the node-fetch module. I have been working on this Angular Firebase project for months now and would appreciate the help. I dont know how to fix it and i accidently did this on my master branch and have found no way to revert it...

I have tried updating my firebase SDK, npm updates, yarn upgrades. I dont know what information to provide. If you feel like you might be able to help please just leave a note as to what other informaiton you may need from me.

Thank you

````
core.mjs:9171 ERROR Error: Service database is not available
    at Provider.getImmediate (index.esm2017.js:147:23)
    at getDatabase (index.esm2017.js:13624:46)
    at new HeroServiceService (hero-service.service.ts:57:25)
    at Object.HeroServiceService_Factory [as factory] (hero-service.service.ts:54:32)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:8719:35)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:8607:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:4782:33)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:4786:12)
    at Object.UserService_Factory [as factory] (user.service.ts:31:25)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:8719:35)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this. I dont know exactly how. But it involved updating dependencies and firebase.

Thank you to anyone who did take a look.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).